# Passing offset difference or constants inside macro

Tags: assembly, emu8086

It's a university assignment, so emu8086 must be used. With no emu8086.inc

Let's say I have

```
msg db "Hello"
msgend:
msglen1 equ $ - msg
msglen2 db $ - msg
```

Then:

```
mov ax, msgend - offset msg ; ax gets the correct length
mov ax, msglen1             ; correct length
mov ax, msglen2             ; correct length

; same names as offsets to make it clear, 
; how which parameters would be passed. 
; But not the same in real code.
TESTMACRO macro msg msgend msglen1 msglen2
    mov ax,    msg ; correct offset
    mov ax, msgend ; correct offset
    mov ax, msgend - offset msg ; zero length
    mov ax, msglen1             ; again zero length
    mov ax, msglen2             ; correct length, but it used up a word
endm
```

So. I can't pass the length of the string inside the macro in any way, except by passing the length allocated in a word.
But I'm interested, if I can do it with a equ constant.

Comment: `mov ax, msglen2` loads a word from a `db`.  It only works because the byte after happens to be zero.  You're correct that it's bad, and you should arrange for the length to be an immediate constant, not stored in memory and loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `=` to define your equate instead of `equ`.

The value of an `equ` equate is evaulated at the point of usage, which in your case means that the `$` in `msglen1` is replaced by the address of the `mov ax, msgLen1` instruction.

The value of an `=` equate is evaulated at the point of definition, which should give you the value you want in this case.

Comment: Surprisingly enough,  it didn't work either. Gives a zero anyway when passed to the macro. I'll get home and check it again. Could it be something is wrong with the macro definition itself?

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd try if I were you would be to not used macro parameter names that shadow global symbol names (e.g. you have an `equ` named `msglen1` and a macro parameter named `msglen1` - if you write `mov ax,msglen1` inside your macro, which of those `msglen1`s should the assembler use?).

Comment: As I said, it was done only here for the sake if an example. I have no shadowing in actual code. The shortest code was  a one line macro with a `var`  parameter and a `mov ax, var`. An =  equate `testvar`  is passed, and ax is still equal to 0. If I do `mov ax, testvar` outside any macro, it gets the correct value

Comment: Oh! Almost forgot. The value is lost only when $  is used in constant definition

Comment: If $ was evaluated at place of use, wouldn't it be equal to something other than $. Unfortunately = didn't work for me either. I hope a null-terminated string will work for the assignment.